# Fixed point at 0 in Slider range component

Tags: javascript, css, slider

Slider has range, max, min, and two possible value. One of value is set fixed at 0, another one can drag to change value In my website, I tried to construct a slider with a range from -10 to 10. There are two possible value input in slider, one value is 0 and it is fixed. Another value can drag and show the value based on the value to 0.

I initially want to disable one of the value input, but it does not work out, and I want to display like this:

[-10] |---------------------|[0]|-----------<->-----------| [ 10]

or

[-10] |----------<->-----------|[0]|----------------------| [ 10]

but not like start from -10.

[-10] |-------------------------------<->------------| [ 10]

It will render the range from 0 to 10 or 0 to -10, but not from -10 to a point. 0 as the fixed number in the slider.

I'm not sure where to start, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen input event and prevent less / more than you want. I made a little hack. But you have to multiply the value of the second input by minus.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

inputs.forEach(p => {
  p.addEventListener("input", () => {
    if (event.target.value >= 0) {
      event.target.value = 0;
    }

    if (event.target.id == "inp1") {
      console.log("first input's value: " + event.target.value)
    }
    if (event.target.id == "inp2") {
      console.log("second input's value: " + event.target.value * -1)
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#inp2 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<input type="range" id="inp1" min="-10" max="10">
<input type="range" id="inp2" min="-10" max="10">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast replying. I am confused about how the progress bar can be rendered from 0 to both side since the starting point is 0. If I have a value of 5, then in your case it will render from -10 to 5 but not from 0 to 5.

Comment: I set zero as a limit. You can set any value you want. You can change the min and max values. I couldn't fully understand what you wanted.

Comment: Hi sorry for the confusion. In the inp2 case, if I have a value of 5, then it will display the progress bar from -10 to 5, and I want it only shows the progress bar from 0 to 5, the progress bar from -10 to 0 will not show, and the range is still from -10 to 10.

Comment: this is not possible. you should use customized slider. like customized checkboxes.